# How to add a hyperlink in static sublist to the specific column in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have GL account column in sublist, I want to navigate to that particular account after clicking on that account name in sublist , so i want to add hyperlink or something to go to that account.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I handle this by adding a 'View' column to my sublist and use the `setLinkText()` function to set the display text.  Then I perform a search to get the records that I want and add them to the sublist.  Then I loop back through the sublist and use `setLineItemValue()` on the View column with the URL that links to the record.

Here's a working Suitelet that lists expense reports for the current user and provides a link to each expense report:

```js
function suitelet(request, response) {
    var form = nlapiCreateForm('Expense Reports');

    var expenseReportList = form.addSubList('custpage_expenses', 'list', 'Expenses');
    expenseReportList.addField('custpage_view', 'url', 'View').setLinkText('View');
    expenseReportList.addField('internalid', 'select', 'Expense Report', 'expensereport').setDisplayType('inline');
    expenseReportList.addField('memo', 'text', 'Memo');
    expenseReportList.addField('amount', 'currency', 'Amount');

    var expenseReports = getExpenseReports(nlapiGetUser());
    expenseReportList.setLineItemValues(expenseReports);

    updateViewRecordLinks(expenseReports, expenseReportList);

    response.writePage(form);
}

function getExpenseReports(employeeId) {
    var results = nlapiSearchRecord('expensereport', null, [
        new nlobjSearchFilter('entity', null, 'anyof', employeeId),
        new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T')
    ], [
        new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid'),
        new nlobjSearchColumn('memo'),
        new nlobjSearchColumn('amount')
    ]);

    return results; 
}

function updateViewRecordLinks(expenseReports, expenseReportList) {
    for (var i = 0; expenseReports && i < expenseReports.length; i++)
    {
        var row = expenseReports[i];
        var viewUrl = nlapiResolveURL('RECORD', 'expensereport', row.getId(), false);
        expenseReportList.setLineItemValue('custpage_view', i + 1, viewUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mark - Its nice alternative solution but i want to add link to that Account column directly , which is dynamically generated after saving my Bill order, so i don't have text to SetLinktext to use url in addField for that column.